# Getting list of all paths which lead to leaf in Python

Tags: python, lambda, binary-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

I have a binary tree, where each node stores a piece of data (`self.pred`). I want to write a function that for each leaf in the tree, returns a list of the data  (which is a lambda function) in the nodes visited to reach that leaf.

For example, I want the function called on this tree:

```
    A 
   / \
 B    C
/ \  / \
1  2 3  4
```

to return:

```
returned_list = [
[A, B, 1]
[A, B, 2]
[A, C, 3]
[A, C, 4]
]
```

To make thinks more complicated, following the right branch to reach a piece of data must return the inverse of the lambda function stored as that node's data.

For example, where `A'` is `not(A)`, the following list must be returned:

```
returned_list = [
[A, B, 1]
[A, B', 2]
[A', C, 3]
[A', C', 4]
]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, pred):
        self.parent = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.pred = pred

def build_tree(pred_choices, k):
    if k == 0:
        return Node(get_pred())
    else:
        node = Node(get_pred())
        node.left = build_tree(pred_choices, k-1)
        node.right = build_tree(pred_choices, k-1)
        return node

def get_paths(root, cur_path, all_paths):
    if (root.left == None and root.right == None): # If leaf, append current path
        all_paths.append(cur_path)
    else:
        get_paths(root.left, cur_path.append(root.pred), all_paths)
        get_paths(root.right, cur_path.append(lambda x: not(root.pred(x)), all_paths)
    return all_paths

def auto_tree_build(pred_choices, k): 
    root = build_tree(pred_choices, k)
    all_paths = get_paths(root, [], [])
    return all_paths
```

But the above code doesn't work, and I do not understand its output. Can someone help me make the above code execute the described behavior?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I would use recursion.

I changed the `Node` class a bit, but you can design it however you like so long as each `Node` stores the left and right children.

```
from copy import copy
from collections import namedtuple


# NodePoint, to distinguish between A and A'
NP = namedtuple('NP', ['node', 'right'])


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, left=None, right=None):
        self.name = name
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


d = Node('1')
e = Node('2')
f = Node('3')
g = Node('4')
b = Node('B', d, e)
c = Node('C', f, g)
a = Node('A', b, c)


def get_routes(node, route=None):
    route = route or []
    # If this node has children, clone the route, so we can process
    # both the right and left child separately.
    if node.right:
        right_route = copy(route)

    # Process the main (left) route.  Pass the route on to the left 
    # child, which may return multiple routes.
    route.append(NP(node, False))
    routes = get_routes(node.left, route) if node.left else [route]

    # If there is a right child, process that as well.  Add the route
    # results.  Note that NP.right is set to True, to indicate a right path.
    if node.right:
        right_route.append(NP(node, True))
        right_routes = get_routes(node.right, right_route)
        routes.extend(right_routes)

    # Pass the results back
    return routes


routes = get_routes(a)

# print out the results.
for route in routes:
    names = []
    for np in route:
        name = '{0}{1}'.format(np.node.name, "'" if np.right else '')
        names.append(name)
    print names

# ['A', 'B', '1']
# ['A', "B'", '2']
# ["A'", 'C', '3']
# ["A'", "C'", '4']
```